# Jquery css function doesnt use all the arguments in a map

Tags: jquery, css

In one of my webApp methods, I create html elements dynamically and add a dynamically made css object using this code :

```
    tag = typeof(tag) !== 'undefined' ? tag : "div";
    end = typeof(end) !== 'undefined' ? end : true;
    var html = '<'+tag+' value="'+this.id+'" class="element '+this.type+'"'+
                'style="position:absolute;z-index= '+this.id+'"'
    end ? html += "></"+tag+">" : html += "/>";
    var css = {},element = this;
    $.each(this.properties(),function(){
        var hash=this.indexOf("Color") !== -1?'#':'';
        var property = typeof(element[this])==='number'?element[this]*Nx.ratio:element[this];
        css[this]=hash+property;
    })
    console.log(css);
    html = $(html).css(css);
    $('.page[value='+page+']').append(html);
```

Here is an example of css object taken from my console.log that was created and passed to the css() function :

```
Object
backgroundColor: "#ff0000"
borderColor: "#ffffff"
borderStyle: "solid"
borderWidth: "0"
height: "56.865"
left: "0"
top: "274.29"
width: "893.115"
__proto__: Object
```

now the problem is that the output element doesnt have the top, left, height and width properties, e.g. :

```
<div value="12" class="element rectangle" style="position: absolute; background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0); left: 0px; border-top-width: 0px; border-right-width: 0px; border-bottom-width: 0px; border-left-width: 0px; border-top-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-right-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-bottom-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-left-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-top-style: solid; border-right-style: solid; border-bottom-style: solid; border-left-style: solid; "></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These CSS properties are not applied to your element because you do not specify them properly. The values of `left`, `top`, `width` and `height` have to be:

- Either a number, such as `0` or `274.29`,
- Or a string followed by a unit suffix, such as `"0px"` or `"274.29px"`.

Your code uses strings without a unit suffix, therefore the values are considered as invalid and the properties are ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks somehow problematic... can't really tell where the error is but you're missing `;` here:

```
...'style="position:absolute;z-index= '+this.id+'"'; <-- there!
```

Also this:

```
tag = typeof(tag) !== 'undefined' ? tag : "div"
```

can also be written as this most of the time:

```
 tag = tag || 'div'
```

Maybe your problem is here, there's a lot of `this` going on...

```
$.each(this.properties(), function () {
    var hash = this.indexOf("Color") !== -1 ? '#' : '';
    var property = typeof(element[this]) === 'number' ? element[this] * Nx.ratio : element[this];
    css[this] = hash + property;
})
```

What's `this.properties()`. Is that `this` the same as the `this` inside `each(...)`? Seems like a source of errors there...

Comment: thanks alot, Frédéric was right though, I should add a "px" at the end of my numbers. But thanks for your tips, I never knew about  tag = tag || 'div' ... is there any where that I can find more of this kind of shorthand coding ?